# Android AutoCompleteTextView suggest alternative

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

is it possible to have an AutoCompleteTextView, that looks for a string, but suggests an alternative string?

For example if the user types in 'Yau' or 'yauh' it would suggest 'Yáuh' so the user isn't required to type in special characters.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a go at extending ArrayAdapter, but it deosn't seem to be overwriting:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;

import android.widget.Filterable;

public class foreignAdapter<T> extends ArrayAdapter implements Filterable {

        String temp;
        String word;

        private List<T> mObjects;
        private final Object mLock = new Object();
        private ArrayList<T> mOriginalValues;

        public foreignAdapter(Context context, int resource, T[] object) {
            super(context, resource, object);


        }




        private class ArrayFilter extends Filter {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence prefix) {
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

                if (mOriginalValues == null) {
                    synchronized (mLock) {
                        mOriginalValues = new ArrayList<T>(mObjects);
                    }
                }

                if (prefix == null || prefix.length() == 0) {
                    synchronized (mLock) {
                        ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<T>(mOriginalValues);
                        results.values = list;
                        results.count = list.size();
                    }
                } 
                else {
                    String prefixString = prefix.toString().toLowerCase();


                    final ArrayList<T> values = mOriginalValues;
                    final int count = values.size();

                    final ArrayList<T> newValues = new ArrayList<T>(count);

                    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                        final T value = values.get(i);
                        final String valueText = value.toString().toLowerCase();

                        /* Run for each character in the string */
                        for(int j=0;j<valueText.length();j++)
                        {

                        switch(valueText.charAt(j))
                        {
                        case 'á':
                        case 'ā':
                        case 'à':
                            temp+='a';
                            break;
                        case 'í':
                        case 'ī':
                        case 'ì':
                            temp+='i';
                            break;
                        case 'è':
                        case 'ē':
                        case 'é':
                            temp+='e';
                            break;
                        case 'ó':
                        case 'ō':
                        case 'ò':
                            temp+='o';
                            break;
                        case 'ú':
                        case 'ū':
                        case 'ù':
                            temp+='u';
                            break;
                        case 'ģ':
                            temp+='g';
                          break;
                        default:
                            temp+=word.charAt(j);
                          break;
                        }

                       }




                        // First match against the whole, non-splitted value
                        if (temp.startsWith(prefixString)) {
                            newValues.add(value);
                        } else {
                            final String[] words = temp.split(" ");
                            final int wordCount = words.length;

                            for (int k = 0; k < wordCount; k++) {
                                if (words[k].startsWith(prefixString)) {
                                    newValues.add(value);
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    results.values = newValues;
                    results.count = newValues.size();
                }

                return results;
            }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            //noinspection unchecked
            mObjects = (List<T>) results.values;
            if (results.count > 0) {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this but this will surely do...

You haven't specified if your data is in an array or a DB so i'm going to assume an array (or a list).

Override the `getFilter()` of your Adapter. (Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6053383/overriding-filterresults-in-android-autocompletetextview) to see how)

Now, in that example (in the link) the author uses `startsWith` to filter the results. Instead you'll have to use your own Comparision Method that will consider those special characters aswell. (as in, equate `á` with `a`)

Answer (score -1):

There's the AutoCompleteTextView, so I guess that's what you need:

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="MyAutoCompleteTextView" >
</AutoCompleteTextView>
```

Here's the official info: [AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html)

I've just seen there's even a tutorial, [Tutorial of AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-autocomplete.html)

Comment: That works fine if you want it to search for a part of a word and suggest the whole word, but that is not what I am wanting to do.

Comment: If what you want is to modify what is being written, then I daresay you will have to write your own function (If string == "Yau" then textview = "Yáuh" )

Comment: @ArcDan, no it is not a simple conversion, as the user may want "Yauh", "Yáuh", "Yāuh" or "Yàuh". so what I want is these listed as suggestions in the autocomplete.  As it seems there is no simple way to do this, I will look at extending AutoCompleteTextView